# Background image rotated itself 90deg

Tags: html, css

I added an background image inside a container that was smaller than the image. It was part of the plan. Even though it automatically rotated itself 90deg, without me touching anything (there was 3 other boxes with the exact same settings, not the same image though.). Any idea how to fix that, or what it is happening?

#### EDIT: Issue solved, Kyle Shrader told me to use and EXIF tool, which I did. That told me the photo was rotated 90 degree, in the metas, even though it looked fine front end. I used an exif editor and put it on Horizontal (normal value for a photo) instead of Rotated 90 CW.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Without this, your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Okay, i will try to photoshop an example.

Comment: @MagnusPilegaard See my comment above, we need to see actual code. Images don't count, but do help **if** there is also code.

Comment: It's i client i'm working for, and its private images. I can send the code, then an photoshop example of the result? Is that okay?

Comment: @MagnusPilegaard Can you just write like <img src="image.png"/> and post an image similar to the one that was giving you issues so these people will give your question credit? :P

Comment: @KyleShrader what do you mean? I voted your question to be correct. How can i explain it those folks? :P

Comment: Man, I wish I knew. I'm trying to figure them out. Don't worry about it, good luck on your project.

Comment: @KyleShrader Look at OP. I tried explaining. Thank you!

Comment: Good, i hope the get it know. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the image has EXIF orientation set, some browsers will interpret this and automatically rotate the image. You can use a tool like [EXIF Data Viewer](http://exifdata.com/index.php) to quickly check that this is not the case for you.

If this is the case, you can solve the issue in your style sheets or in the image file itself.

To solve this problem with CSS, use the image-orientation css property to set your image orientation. `image-orientation: 0deg;` is what you could use, in your case.

To remove the EXIF tag from the file, you can use a tool like <s>[theXifer](http://thexifer.net/)</s> [EXIF Purge](http://www.exifpurge.com/)

edit: replaced the originally linked online solution with an offline solution. With each there are concerns. Online solutions pose an issue to leaking company information or assets. Obviously you should only use trusted offline solutions, since this could pose a security risk. Thank you for the recommendation, @TomerOfer

Comment: It was, even though that in browsers, photoshop etc, it shows as no rotation, this tool tells me different. How do i change that? Thanks.

Comment: Just curious, which browser are you using? Does the rotation happen in chrome as well?

Comment: the rotation happens in both Chrome and safari

Comment: Oh interesting. The compatibility on image-orientation seems to be limited to Firefox so I'd suggest you stick with editing it in the file directly.

Comment: Seems like image-orientationer isnt supported. Hmm

Comment: Thank you! Your solution worked, i found an exif editor online and solved it that way. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!
i used this: http://www.exifpurge.com/
hate online tools...

Comment: Great link @TomerOfer ... I'm going to start using that.

Edit: I think anyone working at a company should adhere to an offline solution because any online solution may claim rights or publicly expose your uploaded product.

Comment: Do not use `image-orientation` it is extremely unsupported.